Writing $2^d$ as a sum of $4$ integer squares, without using Jacobi's theorem
Find all the ways to write $2^d$ ($d$ is a positive integer) as a sum of four integer squares, without using Jacobi's four-square theorem.

According to Jacobi's theorem, for every positive integer $d$ we have in total $24$ ways to write $2^d$ as a sum of four integer squares.
I found all of them:

If $d=2k+1$ is odd, permutations of:
$$(\pm2^k)^2+(\pm2^k)^2+0^2+0^2$$

If $d=2k$ is even, permutations of:
$$(\pm2^k)^2+0^2+0^2+0^2$$
or
$$(\pm2^{k-1})^2+(\pm2^{k-1})^2+(\pm2^{k-1})^2+(\pm2^{k-1})^2$$


Since I can't use Jacobi's theorem, how can I show there are no other ways to do so?
I tried to prove it by induction on $d$, but no success. If I can show that:
$2^d=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2$ where $x_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $d>2$
implies that all $x_i$ must be even, so I can do it using the idea of induction.
Thanks!

Why don't you want to use Jacobi's four square theorem? We should be happy to use it.

Haha, couldn't agree more, but this if for some exercise .

From this identity it fallows : $$2^m=2^d+2^d+0^2+0^2$$ where d is any positive integer & $m=d+1$.

The LHS of $2^d$ being even means the number of odd terms on the RHS is even (i.e., $4$, $2$ or $0$) so, correspondingly, $0$, $2$ or $4$ of the $x_i$ values are even. With $0$ of them being even, i.e., all $4$ are odd, we have
$$x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2 \equiv 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 \equiv 4 \pmod{8}$$
If $2$ of them are even instead, say WLOG the first $2$ terms, then the last $2$ are odd, so we then get
$$x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2 \equiv 0 + 0 + 1 + 1 \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$$
However, note $d \gt 2$ means that
$$2^d \equiv 0 \pmod{8}, \;\; 2^d \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$$
which contradicts the first $2$ equations. Thus, there can't be either $0$ or $2$ even $x_i$ values but, instead, all $4$ of the $x_i$ must be even. You can therefore use this with induction to complete your proof, as you've stated.
